# <blockquote> tag inserted when using image in cell of RST table?

Tags: image, restructuredtext

When I use the following code:

```
+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          A           |       B       |                C                                                    |
+======================+===============+=====================================================================+
| Merchant Rating      | Ad Extension  | Star ratings plus number of reviews for the advertiser/merchant.    |
|                      |               |                                                                     |
|                      |               |.. image:: /images/merchant-rating.png                               |
+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The text *preceding* the image in column C gets wrapped in `<blockquote>` tags in the HTML output. Is there any way to avoid this?

[image: Text impacted by arbitrary <blockquote> tag in column C]

Comment: Would you post the source code associated with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `blockquote` tag in the first paragraph of the third column, you could try using this:

```
+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          A           |       B       |                C                                                    |
+======================+===============+=====================================================================+
| Merchant Rating      | Ad Extension  | Star ratings plus number of reviews for the advertiser/merchant.    |
|                      |               |                                                                     |
|                      |               | |img|                                                               |
+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

.. |img| image:: /images/merchant-rating.png
```

Instead, you'll get two paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [substitution](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-references) and remove the separating line so that Sphinx interprets the content as a single block of text.

```
+-----------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        A        |      B       |                C                                                 |
+=================+==============+==================================================================+
| Merchant Rating | Ad Extension | Star ratings plus number of reviews for the advertiser/merchant. |
|                 |              | |img|                                                            |
+-----------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

.. |img| image:: /images/merchant-rating.png
```

Comment: I actually had to take a different approach, but thanks for the suggestions. I still don't understand why a previous paragraph would be impacted. Is there some benefit to this behavior that I don't understand?

Comment: Whitespace has meaning in reST. Without a substitution, you would have to have the text on one line, then a blank line, then the `image` directive, all of which is interpreted as two blocks of content or two paragraphs.